# what are these gloves called?

Tags: names, image-identification

Gloves that have only two compartments, one for the thumb and the other wide enough for four fingers. What are they called?

[image: Strange Gloves]

Comment: Nowadays, thanks to Google, you can search for images on the Internet and set your preferred  language to *English".

Comment: _Raindrops on roses and whiskers on kittens // Bright copper kettles and warm woollen **mittens** // Brown paper packages tied up with strings //
These are a few of my favorite things_ [The Sound of Music](http://www.metrolyrics.com/my-favorite-things-maria-lyrics-the-sound-of-music.html)

Comment: When I lived in Alberta in the early 1970s, the common term for these items was _mitts_. But everywhere else I've lived, they were called _mittens_.

Comment: Yep, definitely "mittens", anywhere in the US except perhaps the Deep South (where folks would look at them and ask "What are those?").  "Mitts" is also used as a shortened form, but risks confusion with a [baseball mitt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseball_glove).

Answer (score 13):

Gloves with one section for four fingers are called [*Mittens*.](https://www.google.co.uk/search?site=&source=hp&q=define+mittens&oq=define+mittens&gs_l=hp.3..0j0i22i30l6j0i22i10i30.685.3241.0.3425.15.14.0.0.0.0.559.2291.0j5j2j1j0j1.9.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..7.8.1732.0.erfj0idSz00)

Answer (score 6):

They are called [mittens](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mittens&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=663&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=lNpeVaLrLOOz7AaFvoOYAQ&ved=0CAYQ_AUoAQ)

Interestingly, there are actually three differing types of mittens and I didn't know there were separate names for them. - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glove#Mittens).

Comment: I was completely confused by your "three types of mittens" statement and I'm not sure it's helpful. When I looked at the list on the Wikipedia page, I'd never heard of any of them before. Additionally, not every mitten falls into one of those three categories.  Most are simply "mittens".

Comment: @Catija I'm not sure why it was confusing to you but I have edited my answer to make it simpler.

Comment: It's generally good practice to actually include the relevant content of your links in your answers... This is because links do die... it also saves people from *necessarily* having to follow the link to the other site to understand what you're saying. I guess that all I'm saying is that, since those terms are not in wide use, it would be good to either not mention them because it could be confusing, or to include their names and definitions but note that the terms are not in regular use.

Comment: @Catija Thanks I will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: The three subtypes mentioned in the Wikipedia article are all special-purpose varieties.